# import _self throwing ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string

Tags: templating, import

`{% import _self as mcr_home %}`

is throwing

> Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string

How is this possible and how do I fix it?

Comment: Any name collisions? With "import", or "_self" or "mcr_home"?

Comment: Can you enable devMode, reproduce the error then share the full stack trace so we can see where the error originates from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, those two have nothing to do with each other. What's more likely is that the error is being triggered **by the imported script**. It's possible that your stack trace is just giving you a red herring by pointing to the import itself.

---

**In your Twig code:**

[`import`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html) pulls in a macro (or macros).

`_self` just means "this template file".

"mcr_home" is just how you're referring to your imported macro(s).

**In the error message:**

An [`ElementCriteriaModel`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) is simply [a model representing a Craft content search](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/2763/45).

"could not be converted to string" is telling you that the model cannot be read as a string.

---

Obviously there is no correlation there. Take a closer look at the macro(s) you are importing... I'm certain you will find an ElementCriteriaModel which is attempting to be used as a string.

Comment: There was a lot of code in the template so the error pointing to that line really threw me off. Turns out it was something in the template that it was extending. {% extends "_layout" %}

Seems strange that the error was so utterly useless.